# How can I sort references by chapter?

Tags: bibliographies, subdividing

I'm writing a report and I'd like to have one bibliography at the end of the document, where the references are sorted by chapter like that :

Chapter 1's title
ref 1
ref 2

Chapter 2's title
ref 4
ref5

Does anyone have an idea of how I could do it?

Comment: Please register your account at Stack Overflow and at TeX Stack Exchange to be able to comment on your question and its answers after the migration, and to accept an answer.

Comment: @Paŭlo, can questions migrate from SO to TeX? It's not among the options I see when I vote off-topic.

Comment: @Henning Only moderators can migrate them to any site in the network. I let a flag, but for now no moderator has acted upon it.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way I am aware of is to use `biblatex`.  For example,

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{memoir}

%refsegment specifies that each chapter will be a
% separate segment of a unified bibliography
\usepackage[refsegment=chapter]{biblatex}

\bibliography{ ... } % reference bib files as per normal

\begin{document}
\chapter{one}
% add some citations

\chapter{two}
% add more citations


% loop over each segment (chapters in this case) and
% \printbibliography for each one
\bibbysegment
\end{document}
```