# Group the references in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, subdividing

I am preparing a report in LaTeX and I have many references which I intend to put in the Bibliography.

I was wondering if it possible to group the reference based on the topic. I would expect a LaTeX output something like this:

> [Section1]
>
> [1] IEEE Standard
>
> [2] Book 1
>
> [Section 2]
>
> [3] Ref 1
>
> [4] Ref 2

This way, it will be useful when we just read the Bibliography part, we can  access the References based on the section of our interest rather than going through all the references.

Comment: related question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26598/how-can-i-sort-references-by-chapter-with-latex

Answer (score 15):

You can use the `refsection` environment and the `section` option of `\printbibliography` to select a reference section. A little example:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{biblio.bib}
@book{goossens93,
    author = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittlebach and Alexander Samarin",
    title = "The {LaTeX} Companion",
    year = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address = "Reading, Massachusetts"

}

@article{greenwade93, 
    author = "George D. Greenwade",
    title = "The {C}omprehensive {TeX} {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
    year = "1993",
    journal = "TUGBoat",
    volume = "14",
    number = "3",
    pages = "342--351",
    url=" www.ctan.org"
}

@book{knuth79,
    author = "Donald E. Knuth",
    title = "{TeX} and Metafont, New Directions in Typesetting",
    year = "1979",
    publisher = "American Mathematical Society and Digital Press",
    address = "Stanford"
}

@book{lamport94,
    author = "Leslie Lamport",
    title = "{LaTeX}: A Document Preparation System",
    year = "1994",
    edition = "Second",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}

@misc{patashnik88,
    author = "Oren Patashnik",
    title = "{BibTeX}ing.  Documentation for General {BibTeX} users",
    year = "1988",
    howpublished = "Electronic document accompanying BibTeX
distribution"
}

@techreport{rahtz89,
    author = "Sebastian Rahtz",
    title = "A Survey of {T}e{X} and graphics",
    year = "1989",
    institution = "Department of Electronics and Computer Science",
    address = "University of Southampton, UK",
    number = "CSTR 89-7"
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\defbibheading{subbibliography}{%
  \section*{References for Section~\ref{refsection:\therefsection}}}

\begin{document}
\section{Test Section One}
\begin{refsection}

\cite{goossens93}, \cite{lamport94}, \cite{rahtz89}
\end{refsection}

\section{Test Section Two}

\begin{refsection}
\cite{greenwade93}, \cite{patashnik88}, \cite{knuth79}
\end{refsection}

\printbibliography[section=1,heading=subbibliography]
\printbibliography[section=2,heading=subbibliography]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: don't know where you got the bib items, but the bracing in names is seriously deficient.  almost everywhere it should be `{T}e{X}` or `{TeX}` and similarly for `LaTeX`.  please fix.

Comment: @barbara beeton: fixed. Thanks for pointing out the deficiencies.

Answer (score 10):

Here is another solution which is more automated:

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    % refsection=chapter,
    refsegment=chapter,
    sorting=none,
    style=numeric
]{biblatex}
%\defbibheading{subbibliography}{%
%  \section*{References for Section~\ref{refsection:\therefsection}}}
\defbibheading{subbibliography}{%
  \section*{References for Segment~\ref{refsegment:\therefsection\therefsegment}}}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
}

%% ##############################
\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet~\cite{sigfridsson}.

\chapter{Another Chapter}
At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum~\cite{kastenholz}.


\chapter{Conclusions}
Cite an author not previously cited~\cite{cicero}.
And then again cite some authoprs cited previously~\cite{kastenholz}.
Note: Alphabetcially, K comes before S.
At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum~\cite{sigfridsson}.

%\printbibliography
\printbibheading
% \bibbysection[heading=subbibliography]
\bibbysegment[heading=subbibliography]

\end{document}
```

It more or less does the same as the answer by Gonzalo Medina, but

- uses `refsegment` instead of `refsection` to ensure unique labels
- the biblatex option `refsegment=chapter` automatically marks each `\chapter{}` as a `refsegment`
- `\bibbysegment` automatically writes a `\printbibliography` command for each `refsegment`

biblatex comes with a lot of [usage examples](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples), the commands used here were more or less directly copied from `12-references-by-segment.tex`