# How to use a separate bibliography at the end of each section?

Tags: bibliographies, subdividing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple Bibliographies](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17474/multiple-bibliographies)

I need to use a separate bibliography at the end of each section in my work, However, after declaring the package `\usepackage{bibunits}` and subsequently, using `\usebibunit`, my TeXnicCenter tells me the command is not recognized! Please, I need help on any other available method.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: This would be very easy using `biblatex`. There are a lot of [examples on how to use biblatex on CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples). You should look at "references per section". Also, this question might be relevant: [Group the references in bibliography](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29318/8569)