# Can citations generated with biblatex be referenced in another document?

Tags: biblatex

I have created a CV where I use the `biblatex` package in order to create multiple bibliographic lists containing my publications sorted into "articles", "inproceedings", etc. Now I want to create another document (an application) where I cite some of these articles. How can I do this without hard-coding the reference numbers from my CV?

I am aware of the package `xcite` (which is similar to the xr-package), but I don't get it to work (probably because of the use of the `biblatex` package which seems create a non-standard `.aux`-file).

Here is a small working example of what I want to achieve:

In CV.tex :

```
\begin{filecontents}{CV_bib.bib}
@article{Einstein1935,
AUTHOR    = {Albert Einstein},
TITLE     = {Can quantum-mechanical description of physical reality be considered complete?},
JOURNAL = {Physical review},
YEAR      = {1935}
}
@unpublished{Einstein1913,
AUTHOR    = {Albert Einstein and Michele Besso},
TITLE     = {Motion of the perihelion of Mercury},
YEAR = {1913}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric-comp,defernumbers]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{CV_bib.bib}

\begin{document}
Some citations: \cite{Einstein1935}, \cite{Einstein1913}.

\textbf{Submitted for review}
\printbibliography[type=unpublished, heading=none]
\textbf{Journal Publications}
\printbibliography[type=article, heading=none]
\end{document}
```

In application.tex :

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcite}
\externalcitedocument{CV}

\title{Application}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

As you can see in \cite{Einstein1913} we did....

\end{document}
```

As you can see I just want to get the correct citation number without printing the bibliography.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I see is to somehow [group the bibliography entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29318/group-the-references-in-bibliography). The intersection should be the first group, numbered independtly before anything else. You can put them in 3 different bib files (one for each and one for both).

If you don't group the entries, the numbering could differ. Even if you can reference the numbering somehow, you could easily end up with a case like this: four bibliography entries, numbered [1], [2], [4], [9].

You can avoid the problem above if you include the documents in the same file, but that could cause other problems...

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this Python script to generate a fake `.aux` file for use with xcite and Biblatex. It is a very crude attempt, but it worked for the case I needed it for. Run it as `python gen_dummy_bib.py CV.bbl CV_fake.aux` where `gen_dummy_bib.py` is the below listed Python script:

```
import sys
import re

replace_count = 1
infile = open(str(sys.argv[1]), 'r')
outfile = open(str(sys.argv[2]), 'w')

for line in infile:
    if '\\entry' in line:
        outfile.write(re.findall('\\\\entry\{[^{]+', line)[0].replace('entry', 'bibcite') + '{' + str(replace_count) + '}\n')
        replace_count += 1

infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

It is very simple and goes through the specified `.bbl` file, assuming `\entry` commands in the file appear in the order they are numbered by in the document. These are then converted to corresponding `\bibcite` commands with their number of appearance in the output `.aux` file.

I have also posted this script as a GitHub [Gist](https://gist.github.com/ThomasA/7833b52350c2f8d21d6e).