# Is it possible to use bibunits and multibib simultaneously?

Tags: subdividing, multibib, bibunits

I'm typesetting a contributed book, which has a whole bunch of chapters written by a different author each. My job is make sure all contributions use more or less the same typesetting conventions and select index words.

For the references we wish to create a separate list for each chapter. Originally I was doing this using `multibib`, but it seems that package actually keeps each .aux file open while running pdflatex, hence now that I've finished editing a bunch of chapters, I'm suddenly running into the limited write-stack.

So I switched to `bibunits`, which is better suited for the job anyway.

However....... one of the contributions actually has four separate bibliographies that go with it. This is again precisely the problem `multibib` tries to solve and I happened to start with this contribution, which explains my original choice for that package.

So what I would like to do, is to use `bibunits` for all contributions and use `multibib` to split the references in this one special contribution. Since `bibunits` closes each unit before continuing to the next unit, I should be safe then wrt the limited write stack. Unfortunately these packages don't work well together, so it seems. I guess this has to do with the fact that both of these try to redefine similar same commands (although, since `multibib` explicitly defines `\citeXXXX` commands for each bibliography unit `XXXX` I kind of expected things to be allright)

The error I'm getting, is the standard, infamous:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
<inserted text> 
                }\endwrite 
l.901 ...liographysyta{syta_vdweygaert-references}

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

What also strikes the eye, is that at some point I get an enormous long list of lines saying:

```
(./bu.aux) (./bu.aux) (./bu.aux) (./bu.aux) (./bu.aux) (./bu.aux) (./bu.aux)
```

Allright... back to what I guess is my question: I tried to get separate reference lists for a single chapter, while also creating references for individual chapters and failed. How can I succeed in doing this?

Comment: Is switching to biblatex an option? Then read on here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26598/how-can-i-sort-references-by-chapter-with-latex (also notice the linked questions at the right side)

Comment: That's a good suggestion, I need to check it out a bit more. The main problem I foresee is that the printer forces use to use the `\cite` command and if I understand things correctly, I'd have to replace these commands with a different `biblatex` command right? On the other hand.... I was already kind of doing that when using `multibib`.... :P

Comment: Hmm, the special .bst files from the publisher also seem to give problems with biblatex. That's a bit more cumbersome.

Comment: If you rely on a .bst file, `biblatex` is unfortunately no option. The whole point of `biblatex` is to get rid of the .bst language and delegate all formatting to style files written in LaTeX.

Comment: Consider to switch to `biblatex`, select a style shippped with it that resembles your style and tweak it with the help of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/guidelines-for-customizing-biblatex-styles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So after some hacking, I actually found a (IMO rather dirty) hack that actually makes things work for me, although with a minor modification: I don't use `bibunits`, but rather `chapterbib`.

The basic reason why they couldn't work together, is that they redefine a common set of commands. Hence the basic idea of my solution: make sure they are never, say 'active', simultaneously. For future reference, let me spill out my solution and the limitations (I'm aware of). All the following should be put in the header of your document.

The solution is designed for a setup with one main file, that uses `\include` to include a file for each chapter. The aim is to 'switch off' the `chapterbib` package *before* including a chapterfile that needs to have separate bibliographies. Notice that this means that this particular chapterfile **can never** have the bare `\cite` command. Any citation **must** be part of some subset that `multibib` deals with

(the reason is that when 'switching off' the `chapterbib` package, the `\cite` command works in the standard way, meaning that the `\bibliography` command corresponding to any `\cite` command in the chapterfile is expected in the *main* file.... hopefully this rather long explanation makes sense.. :P)

**Step 1**: create a backup of the commands that will be overwritten by loading `multibib`/`chapterbib`:

```
\makeatletter
\let\orig@bibliography\bibliography
\let\orig@thebibliography\thebibliography
\let\orig@include\include
\let\orig@cite\cite
\let\orig@nocite\nocite
\let\orig@bibliographystyle\bibliographystyle
\makeatother
```

**Step 2**: load `multibib` and define the required bibliography groups you need. Let me remind you again, that later on `chapterbib` will be 'switched off' whenever we make `multibib` 'active'. The consequence is that **each citation** inside a chapterfile that is processed by `multibib` **must** be part of some group, ie you can only use `\citeXXX` commands for groups you created using `\newcites{XXX}{Some title}`. So e.g. one could have:

```
\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{main}{\refname}
\newcites{man}{Manuscripts}
\newcites{com}{Complete Works}
```

**Step 3**: the `multibib` package actually only rewrites the `\bibliography` and `\thebibliography` command. Next store these rewritten versions and move back to the original versions:

```
\makeatletter
\let\mbb@bibliography\bibliography
\let\mbb@thebibliography\thebibliography

\let\bibliography\orig@bibliography
\let\thebibliography\orig@thebibliography

\makeatother
```

**Step 4**: as far as the `chapterbib` package is concerned, it is as if the `multibib` was never loaded, so we can safely load the former package and store the changes it made:

```
\usepackage{chapterbib}

\makeatletter
\let\cpb@bibliography\bibliography
\let\cpb@thebibliography\thebibliography
\let\cpb@bibliographystyle\bibliographystyle
\let\cpb@include\include
\let\cpb@cite\cite
\let\cpb@nocite\nocite
```

**Step 5**: this step is at your own convenience and mainly safes typing - it entails creating a set of macros that allow easily switching between '`chapterbib`-mode' and '`multibib`-mode':

```
\def\bibmulti{% switch to multibib-mode
\let\bibliography\mbb@bibliography%
\let\thebibliography\mbb@thebibliography%
\let\bibliographystyle\orig@bibliographystyle%
\let\include\orig@include%
\let\cite\orig@cite%
\let\nocite\orig@nocite%
}

\def\bibchapter{% switch to 'chapterbib'-mode
\let\bibliography\cpb@bibliography
\let\thebibliography\cpb@thebibliography
\let\bibliographystyle\cpb@bibliographystyle
\let\include\cpb@include
\let\cite\cpb@cite
\let\nocite\cpb@nocite
}
\makeatother
```

**Towards your document**: so how to use all this? This is what your 'main' file could look like using the `bibmulti` and `bibchapter` macros:

```
\documentclass{article} % or whatever class you want
\begin{document}
\include{chapter1}
\include{chapter2}
\bibmulti
\include{chapter3}
\bibchapter
\include{chapter4}
\end{document}
```

This assumes the above described header, where indeed `chapterbib` is loaded second. That package will kick in for the first two chapters, each of which should have commands:

```
\bibliographystyle{your_favourite_style}
\bibliography{your_bibtex_database}
```

Then, just before including chapter three, we 'switch off' `chapterbib` and 'switch on' `multibib`; this file should use the special citation commands created by `multibib`, e.g.:

```
\citemain{ref1}
\citemain{ref2}
\citeman{manuscript1}
% etc...
% etc...
\bibliographystylemain{style_for_main}
\bibliographymain{main_references}

\bibliographystyleman{style_for_manuscripts}
\bibliographyman{manuscript_references}

\nocitecom{*}
\bibliographystylecom{style_for_com}
\bibliographycom{complete_works_references}
```

Then, after chapter 3 was processed, the `bibchapter` macro again switches to using the `chapterbib` version of the citation macros. So when chapter 4 is included, we're back to the original situation and the `chapterbib` package will again make sure that a separate reference list is created for that chapter.

I hope this explains covers enough for others. Maybe for reference I should mention that after TeXing this document, you'll need to run `bibtex` on the chapter files for chapters 1,2 and 4 (`chapterbib` writes citations inside the '.aux' file for the separate chapters) and on the files *main.aux*, *man.aux* and *com.aux* (these are the files created by `multibib`)

**Limitations**
Each time you call `\newcite`, an element is pushed to the write-stack (I think). By using this setup you prevent having to do that for each chapter, but still if you have many chapters that need to be dealt with by `multibib` you'll likely still hit the limit of the write stack. In other words: this setup is designed for the case where the situation of multiple sets of references per chapter is rare (actually, in my particular case there is only one such chapter)

There may be other limitations I'm not aware of. I'm just a newbie at writing TeX for my LaTeX documents, so I really can't give guarantees about the applicability of this solution to other systems and related situations.

Comment: Cheers, this was mightily useful. It's probably worth mentioning that if using the `\citewhatever{}` commands in a figure caption, must remember to add it as `\protect\citewhatever{}`, otherwise all heck breaks loose.