# multiple bibliographies in thesis

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, subdividing

I am writing my PhD thesis using TeXmaker.

```
%---------------------Preamble---------------%
\documentclass[b5paper,twoside,10pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}       
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\pagenumbering{gobble}                      
\usepackage{graphicx}                       
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}     
\providecommand\phantomsection{}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

%---------------------Document starts here---------------%
\begin{document}

\input{titlepage}
\input{dedication}
\input{abstract}

%---------------------Chapters in the thesis---------------%

\input{chapter1}
\input{chapter2}

%------------------------------------%

\end{document} 

%------------------------------------%
```

within each chapter: a separate bibliography and bibliography style (unsrt) is defined.

When I do: bibtex chapter1, I get an error:

Process started I couldn't open file name `chapter1.aux' 
Process exited normally.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I'm not an expert on it, but doesn't `chapterbib` want your chapters `include`d rather than simply `input`?

Comment: How about this? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17474/multiple-bibliographies

Comment: You are using `\input` which doesn't create an auxiliary file. Use `\include` instead. See my answer.

Comment: Also, you really should consider [switching to biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5091/what-to-do-to-switch-to-biblatex)

Comment: @ Matth: Why would you say so? I think it is much more work with biblatex than bibtex. @ Paul and Herbert: \include works...thanks.

Comment: @abhishek Sorry, didn't see your comment because of the space between the @ and my name. I wrote an answer below that demonstrates how to achieve what you requested, I believe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `biblatex` will give you more or less the power and benefits from all specialized packages combined in one, the only drawback is that many journals do not accept `biblatex`, but in my experience that is also the case for `bibtex`. For your PhD thesis, you are free to choose, so I would recommend `biblatex`, because it is powerful and flexible.

Below is a working example, mainly copied form Herberts example.
You just have to run `pdflatex`-`biber`-`pdflatex` to see the output.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{filecontents}
%
\begin{filecontents*}{chap1.tex}
\chapter{Introduction}  
 \blindtext~\parencite{bertram} 
 \blindtext~\textcite{doody}
 \printbibliography[segment=1,heading=subbibliography]
\end{filecontents*}
%
\begin{filecontents*}{chap2.tex}
\chapter{Grundlagen} 
 \blindtext~\citep{aksin} 
 \blindtext~\citet{glashow}
\printbibliography[segment=2,heading=subbibliography]
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[refsegment=chapter,style=numeric,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}

\begin{document}
\include{chap1}
\input{chap2}
\end{document}
```

Some more comments: `biblatex` does not use the `aux` file, so you can use `include` or `input` as you prefer. `biblatex-examples.bib`is a file that is included with all major distributions, use a different name for your own `.bib` file.

If you want to learn more, take a look at [these examples](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples) or start reading [some of the biblatex questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biblatex?sort=votes), for example [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26598/how-can-i-sort-references-by-chapter) or [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29318/group-the-references-in-bibliography).

Answer (score 6):

Without using `\include` you have to use the command `\cbinput` and the environment `cbunit` in the several input files.

Here is a *complete* minimal example for `chapterbib` (load it *before* `babel`!) with `\include` which makes more sense:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{chap1.tex}
\chapter{Introduction} foo 
 \ldots~\cite{book-full} \ldots
 \bibliographystyle{alpha} \bibliography{xampl}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{chap2.tex}
\chapter{Grundlagen} bar
 \ldots~\cite{article-full} 
 \bibliographystyle{plain} \bibliography{xampl}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
% bibtex chap1  bibtex chap2
\begin{document}
\include{chap1}
\include{chap2}
\end{document}
```

running

```
pdflatex test.tex
bibtex chap1
bibtex chap2
pdflatex test.tex
pdflatex test.tex
```

has the output:

[image]

The bibfile `xampl.bib` is part of any TeX distribution.